# Which area is more fundamental: parallelogram or triangle?

Tags: triangles, area, rectangles

After years of studying math, I still have this basic question.

I learned areas of square, triangle, and others as they are by listening to what was told in elementary school. However, I then know a rectangle is just two right triangles and a right triangle is half of a rectangle. Hence, when asked by non-math people why a rectangle's area is its length times height, I usually used two right triangles, then used the summation of the known formula of triangle's area. However, it definitely works either way.

So I am pretty sure something must be asked by me about the definition of area. I just thought that I can get a triangle by cutting a parallelogram which is just a rectangle with a part sliced and moved to the other end, but I also can get a parallelogram by combining two triangles, and do a reverse step to get a rectangle. Then, which one comes first, egg or chicken?

I looked at the Wiki page and it looks like we can use an axiom which is based on rectangle. Or that we assume a square of sides 1 has area 1 and deduce everything from it by slicing, etc. However, I also think that triangle is more fundamental as only by using at least three sides/lines (Euclidean plane), we can finally has an enclosed area, whereas four sides are not necessary.

Does it work either way? Thanks for the lights. :)

EDIT: My guess is that it works either way, but, perhaps, a square is more natural/intuitive/easier, I guess? Not quite sure hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuitive way, as you were probably taught as a child, is to count squares on graph paper. The next step is to draw the formula for the rectangle, $a=w\times h$.

Neither triangle nor parallelogram comes first, and this is because they require *three* directions (or three lengths), when the rectangle only needs *two*.

Also note that the area of the triangle under the form $\dfrac{w\times h}2$ is "teachable", while Heron's formula $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ cannot be explained early.

This said, an important formula is the *shoelace*, that computes the area of an arbitrary polygon. It is based on the area of… the trapezoid.

---

There remains an argument in favor of the triangle: it can be used to *triangulate* any polygonal shape without overlaps. But you can't "parallelogrammize" anything.

Comment: I see. Square is more intuitive indeed.

Comment: @10understanding: I meant rectangle, not square.